# mysql select query not getting executed without limit

Tags: php, mysql, sql, large-data

I copied the contents of a large data table from one table to another with 2 additional columns,
the table1(original data) is getting queried by

```
select * from cc2;
```

But the same data with 2 more additional columns having NULL values throughout are not getting executed normally. i have to put limit clause to make it execute. like

```
select * from cc *limit 0,68000*;
```

the database is same, table and content are same. the question is WHY this weird behavior. and to parse my this data to `foreach()` loop, i am having to run `for()` loop and it is affecting the performance.
Any suggestions would be tried and tested asap.

Thanks in advance geniuses

Comment: php could be running out of memory, but that depends on your script.  Is this a query you have to do just once?

Comment: have set max execution time to -1, and time limit to 0. still not able to run it succesfully from php

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using php for importing a lot of data, just try to execute directly from the commandline.

first dump your table:

`mysqldump -u yourusername -p yourpassword yourdatabase tableName > text_file.sql`

then change the tablename in the top of that file (and make sure the extra columns have default NULL ). And import with

`mysql -u yourusername -p yourpassword yourdatabase < text_file.sql`

Using a textfile containing the query is always preferred for large data sets, so you don't run into problems with PHP or the webserver.

Comment: I tried using mysql command line, it works fine. but i was trying to do that from php script. is it possible to run mysql cli from php script? new to this. thanks for the help